# Add OGC Server to ESRI to ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, ogc

My clients have an existing ESRI ArcGIS Server with an old Silverlight API based online mapping tool.

As part of a large development program a non ESRI tool will be used to host many forms of data resulting from a large range of automated processes, only some of which will have Lat/Long components.

Is it possible to register an external (non ESRI based) OGC server with ArcGIS Server, so a single restful query to ArcGIS server via say an identify tool will result in both the ArcGIS Server based, and the external OGC based data being queried and then returned?

Comment: Server serves data based on map projects it has been instructed to serve. It doesn't accept registrations to other servers. While you could create an SOE to do this, it would very much require reinventing the wheel, and require far more effort than a basic proxy servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You can only publish specific service types to ArcGIS server based off licensing. ArcGIS server isn't a API gateway. You could install Tomcat server separately and combine and ArcGIS server REST services and your OGC services wrapped into one REST service on Apache, but that is another post entirely.

With ArcGIS server you can add datasources. And you can point to a database that is remote as long as ArcGIS server has access to it. And then once it's registered as a datasource then any service pointed to the database would have a recognized datasource. If the OGC services have an accessible data source, then that could be registered in ArcGIS and then published.

But to answer your question no you can't do what you're asking with ArcGIS server.

Comment: Thanks folks.
So is sounds like I could write an SOI to intercept the rest calls, call the other OGC based server and merge the results.
Otherwise I could write a web service which combines the results from both systems and returns the result to the client.
Or I could setup ArcGIS Sever as a OGC service, then make the call to the other OGC system, it can be setup I believe to act in a federated manner, so both OGC services get called.
I also came across the ESRI GeoPortal which seems to let you register ArcGIS Server, and OGC servers and also has an inbuilt mapping control?

Comment: Yes Portal is a newer product. It has an ArcGIS server, and allows you to publish hosted feature services, I'm not sure about OGC services. ArcGIS Portal can be separate from ArcGIS Server, but also communicate. One more option would be to not use ArcGIS server and use GeoServer which is an open source GIS server, and also publishes OGC compliant services.

Comment: Hiya, yeah thanks for the pointer, I have just begun investigating GeoServer and GeoNetwork. 

Idea is to use either as a broker/harvester to being in data from the two systems setup as WFS/WMS (ArcGIS Server), and CSW (The other system). 

The mapping clients call the WFS/WMS endpoints on the GeoServer or GeoNetwork broker, sound reasonable?

Comment: I should add that the client we are doing the work for will always have data in ArcGIS Server. They have licenses and all of their own client companies send and expect to recieve data in an ESRI format. 

The other system mentioned (a distributed framework) is crunching large datasets of survey data in realtime in an automated fashion.